# How to call applet from JSF application?

Tags: java, jsf, applet

I am working in a JSF project and I need to configure a Figure Touch Device in my JSF project. The problem is that the Figure Touch Application is developed as an applet. I want to call the applet from the JSF application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at calling an applet from JavaScript.
Do a google for calling applet from JavaScript